# Add Azure Government storage account in HDInsight

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-hdinsight, azure-gov

I have an HDInsight cluster in Azure Government and want to add an additional storage account that resides in Azure Government.
I’m attempting to do this via the portal’s **Script Actions > + Submit New > Add an Azure Storage account** and providing my Azure Government storage account’s name and key.
This fails with the error (from the cluster’s output file in `/var/lib/ambari-agent/data/output-XXXX.txt`):

```
Key encryption is enabled STORAGE ACCOUNT IS: testgovwebiaasdiag
Validate storage account creds: Invalid Credentials provided for
storage account ('Start downloading script locally: ',

u'https://hdiconfigactions.blob.core.windows.net/linuxaddstorageaccountv01/add-storage-account-v01.sh')
Fromdos line ending conversion successful ('Unexpected error:',
"('Execution of custom script failed with exit code', 139)")
```

Looking at the documentation for “[Add additional storage accounts to HDInsight](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-add-storage)”, there is no indication that [this script](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-add-storage#the-script) supports Azure Government. 
What is the recommended path forward? Should I download the script and modify it? If so, what modifications are needed to support Azure Government?

Answer (score 1):

At this time, **the out of the box *"Add additional storage accounts to HDInsight"* script does not support Azure Government**.

This is because it does not allow for the storage endpoints to be set for the [different Azure Government endpoints](https://aka.ms/azuregovendpoints).

I have created **[this script](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/gsacavdm/0ce736f74336372f9327627e24d490e2/raw/efac00eb993a4f2d6eb1db2725721b7690bb32d5/add-storage-account-gov-v01.sh) which supports Azure Goverment.** It is a modified version of the out of the box one that overrides the endpoints with those for Azure Government.

You can use this script via **Script Actions > + Submit New > - Custom**  and provide this URI in the **Bash script URI**. You can then provide the same parameters, storage account name and storage account key and run you script.

To get support for Azure Government in the out of the box script, please vote for this in the [Azure Government feedback forum](https://aka.ms/azuregovfeedback): **[Support for Azure Government storage accounts in HDInsight](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/558487-azure-government/suggestions/34310731-support-for-azure-government-storage-accounts-in-h)**